# Add RetryWhen to Single When DB Insert Fails

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java2, rx-android

I've been trying to figure this out still new to RXJava and still not liking it, rather use Livedata and coroutines but anyway..  I have this:

```
Single.just(entity)
    .map {
         insertDb(it)
         return@map it
    }
.doOnSubscribe { Timber.d("Updating in database") }
.doOnSuccess { Timber.d("Added row in database") }
.doOnError { Timber.e(it, "Unable to insert object in db") }


fun insertDb(entity: T) {
    try {
       // basic update or insert database.begingTransaction() and endTransaction()
    } catch (e: SQLiteDatabaseLockedException) {}
}
```

So when the error of DB locked occurs I want to catch it and retry the insert using the Single with a retryWhen().  The examples I read are very convoluted and not quite what I want.  And don't worry about the locked DB stuff this is just an example of how I would catch DB errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `PublishProcessor`:

```
 val retryProcessor = PublishProcessor.create<Unit>()

 Single.just("Entity")
       .map { insertDB(it) }
       .doOnError { Log.e(TAG, "Error") }
       .retryWhen { retryProcessor }
       .subscribe { entity -> Log.i(TAG, "Success: $entity") }
```

Insert to DB:

```
fun insertDB(entity: String): String {
    // Insert to DB
    return entity
}
```

Whenever you want to perform a retry, call `onNext` on the `PublishProcessor`:

```
retryProcessor.onNext(Unit)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to retry when a specific exception occurs in the stream, the `retry(N)` operator would probably be better here. (Where N is the max number of times you want to retry the subscription).

```
Single.just(entity)
    .map {
         insertDb(it)
         return@map it
    }
    .retry(1) { e -> e is SQLiteDatabaseLockedException }
```

You also don't want to catch the exception in your `insertDb()` function, let it fall into the error stream so you can catch it inside your `retry` function.

You might also might want to consider returning a `Single` or `Completable` from `insertDb()`, then you call it like `insertDb(entity).retry(1)...` without using that awkward `map` that returns itself.

Your `insertDb()` function would become something like this:

```
fun <T> insertDb(entity: T): Completable {
    return Completable.fromCallable {  
        // Insert operation
    }
}
```